# Compare current HTML with data returned from PHP AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, string-comparison

I'm having issues comparing current list items on a page with ones that are retrieved through a PHP AJAX refresh. I only want the box to refresh if there are new items.

The PHP returns a bunch of formatted, HTML list items.

```
<ul class="socialFeed twitterFeed">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            refreshTweets();
        });
        function refreshTweets() {
            $.get("php/tweets.php", function(data){
                var current = $(".socialFeed.twitterFeed").html();
                if(current != data) {
                    $(".socialFeed.twitterFeed").hide().html(data).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval("refreshTweets()", 2000);
    </script>
</ul>
```

I can't figure out why the string comparison isn't working. I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: What do `console_log`'s of `data` and `current` give you? You'd better save an old version of `data` to compare against. Apart from that I would try to modify the php to save a timestamp (in for example a session) so that you can use that to get only the tweets since that time.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the html generated from the dom will be the same as the html the dom was built from.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, Musa?

Comment: You will need to change the way you comparing your data. Ins't these tweets have any identifier?

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/39me6/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that, Musa. This is good to know for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul class="socialFeed twitterFeed">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var current;
        $(function() {
            refreshTweets();
        });
        function refreshTweets() {
            $.get("php/tweets.php", function(data){
                if(current != data) {
                    current = data;
                    $(".socialFeed.twitterFeed").hide().html(data).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(refreshTweets, 2000);
    </script>
</ul>
```